# Prolog grouping over control

Tags: database, prolog, logic

I am trying to solve a problem by using Prolog.

I got a list of facts `book/2` which represent a `book(title,author)`.

```
...
book('Kamizelka', 'Boleslaw Prus').
book('Katarynka', 'Boleslaw Prus').
book('Kazania sejmowe', 'Piotr Skarga').
book('Konrad Wallenrod', 'Adam Mickiewicz').
...
```

My question is: is there any way to input one query to list all titles grouped by authors? I mean, without typing many ways book(Any,'author1'). book(Any,'author2').

Comment: There is not problem with prolog language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `setof/3` predicate for that:

```
group_author(Author,Books) :-
    setof(Book,book(Book,Author),Books).
```

If we query it then, we obtain:

```
?- group_author(Author,Books).
Author = 'Adam Mickiewicz',
Books = ['Konrad Wallenrod'] ;
Author = 'Boleslaw Prus',
Books = ['Kamizelka', 'Katarynka'] ;
Author = 'Piotr Skarga',
Books = ['Kazania sejmowe'].
```

`setof/3` takes three arguments:

1. the yield, the result we are interested in (here `Book`);
2. the goal, the goal that Prolog should aim to satisfy, (here `book(Book,Author)`); and
3. the set, the resulting set, a list that contains the results without duplicates (here `Books`).